# Haskell - Printing elements of a tuple

Tags: haskell, printing, dictionary

I know that I can print line-by-line the tuples in a list of tuples like this:

```
Prelude> mapM_ print [(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9)]
(1,1)
(2,4)
(3,9)
```

But suppose that I want to output this to a CSV file and I want to output this

```
Prelude> ??? [(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9)]
1,1
2,4
3,9
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
showTup :: (Show a, Show b) => (a,b) -> String
showTup (a,b) = (show a) ++ "," ++ (show b)

λ> mapM_ (putStrLn . showTup) [(1,1), (2,4), (3,9)]
1,1
2,4
3,9
```

Since Haskell is so awesome, you can just write a function that converts a tuple to a string, and since `print` is just `(putStrLn . show)` you can substitute `show` by your own function.

Comment: Wow, that was fast.  Thanks!